# Prove that if 51 positive integers between 1 and 100 are chosen, then one of them must divide another.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Given $51$ integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{51}$ satisfying $1 \leq a_i \leq 100$. Prove that there exist $i$ and $j$ such that $a_i \mid a_j$.

I'm a little unsure how to approach this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: Put two numbers $a\lt b$ in the same hole if $\frac{b}{a}$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Awesome username. You say you are unsure how to approach the problem, but have you tried anything? If this result seems like it *should* be true, you may try to approach this by contradiction. That could produce a proof by contradiction for you or cement why the result is necessarily true.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware that it should be done using the pigeonhole principle, but I just learned of it recently so was unsure of how it applies to this problem. I'll start with going over that material again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More explicit hint (than Andre's comment): each integer in $\{1,\ldots,100\}$ can be written as $2^mn$ where
$$
n\in A=\{1,3,\ldots,99\}.
$$
Note that $|A|=50$, exactly $1$ fewer than $51$. Can you see now how to apply the pigeonhole principle? In particular, if $x=2^{m_1}n$ and $y=2^{m_2}n$ where $n$ is the same for both $x$ and $y$, can you say something about the divisibility between $x$ and $y$?